# using carbon to change utc to other timezone gives the same result

Tags: php, laravel-5, timezone, php-carbon

In my db, the time is saved as utc.

I am trying to use carbon (doesn't have to be carbon) and change it to other timezone such as pacific timezone or America/Vancouver when passing data to the front end.  I want to keep the db having utc which would be more flexible in the future.

But somehow I am getting the same result when I used carbon

```
$tz = $tt->created_at;  // "2019-01-16 18:21:31"
$date = Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $tz, 'America/Vancouver');
dd($tz, $date);
```

`$date` gives me the result of

```
Carbon @1547691691 {#212
  date: 2019-01-16 18:21:31.0 America/Vancouver (-08:00)
}
```

when I do `dd($tz, $date->toDateTimeString());`

I get

```
"2019-01-16 18:21:31"  // $tz
"2019-01-16 18:21:31"  // $date->toDateTimeString()
```

shouldn't `$date->toDateTimeString()` be `"2019-01-16 10:21:31"` because the time is -08:00?

Can someone please give me a hand on what I have done wrong here?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

When you use createFromFormat you are creating a Carbon Object as you can read in the [documentation](https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/)  with *2019-01-16 18:21:31* **DateTime** in **America/Vancouver** timezone

But what you actually want to do is converting your UTC time to America/Vancouver time.

You should create DateTime with UTC Timezone

```
$tz = $tt->created_at;  // "2019-01-16 18:21:31" (UTC Time)
$date = Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $tz, 'UTC');
```

So your DateTime Object is in **UTC** like your Database and then convert it to **America/Vancouver** time

```
$date->setTimezone('America/Vancouver'); // "2019-01-16 10:21:31" (America/Vancouver Time)
```

Comment: Just wondering, if I am not using `setTimeZone` I actually want to use `GMT` hour difference how can this be done? I am thinking if using timezone would be better or the hour